# import Pandas: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, pandas, module, analytics

I am trying to use pandas within my code for data analytics. When importing the module, I get the following error:
`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

I initially tried uninstalling python, pandas, and scikit...hoping that it was a matter of either updating or a simple glitch. I also tried following the solutions to similar issues found on Stack Overflow with no success.

I saw that this issue seemed to have been addressed within Pandas (see [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/403f38da35ab04d3997f61db3c98134fe02910d3)) , but still can't seem to import the module. Has anyone else run into this problem while using Pandas? Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

-Alon

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "predict_from_text.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pandas
File "/Users/alonyoeli/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    import parser
File "/Users/alonyoeli/Desktop/twitter_data/parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    output_json = json.loads(output)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace

Comment: Full traceback of error + your import code would help

Comment: @DeepSpace full stack trace should be provided (if I understand correctly...Sorry this is my first question on Stack)

Comment: @AlonYoeli it looks like the problem is calling `json.loads()` with invalid arguments. What is `output`? Usually you would open a file with `open()` first. I.E: with `open("my_file.json", "r") as f: json.loads(f)`. You need to provide the code part that is giving error as well.

Comment: @umutto In reality I'm trying to use an existing example for my own purposes. Here is a link to it: https://gist.github.com/dansbecker/f1a39119168573de4acc4f29176ea286

Comment: the actually line of code that is giving me an error is 'import pandas as pd' @umutto

Comment: @AlonYoeli yeah you are right, I missed that error is coming from `import pandas` line. Moreover it looks like its coming from `setuptools` or `pkg_manager`. You may have a corrupted python install. I don't know what to recommend but re-installing python via [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: @umutto ok thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get pandas to import! The error was due to permissions or directory organization. Thanks to all who tried to help out!